# UINavigationController toolbar 100% transparent

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, transparent, uitoolbar

In a storyboard I create a `![UINavigationController]` with its root view controller a `UIViewcontroller`. In the toolbar I have a segmented control. I made it transparent, but only has the normal tint, I expect to see the normal background or the table view blurred under it, but its 100% transparent for some reason.

[image]

Comment: How are your edge insets set for the view controllers?

Comment: I haven't set them but on iOS 7 i think they are default to expand under the toolbar and navigation bars. Im expect it to show the content under the toolbar, but to be blurred. For some reason, the toolbar has no background

Comment: Could you please show us a screenshot of your Interface Builder with the toolbar settings?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in iOS7, when presenting a popover from a bar button item.

First open a bug report so Apple gives this issue more priority.

As a workaround, make sure to set the edges for extended layout to none for view controllers inside popovers. For reference, you can see in Apple's calendar app they also do this. There is no translucency under popover navigation bars and toolbars.